# CoreImage face detection happening every frame

Tags: ios, face-detection, core-image

I'm currently exploring face detection functionality in Apple's Core Image framework.

Right now, I'm playing with Apple's sample project which puts red square around person's face. (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SquareCam/Introduction/Intro.html)

The problem I have is that face detection happens every frame so size of red square changes crazily even if I do not move my face.

I acknowledge that following method runs face detection.

```
NSArray* features = [detector featuresInImage:image];
```

And I can manipulate with eye, mouth positions in following loop:

```
for(CIFaceFeature* feature in features)
{

}
```

Is there any way I can smooth the size of red square(area of face) over time? In other words, I wanna minimize the change in the size of red square if person's face is not moving.

p.s. I'm ok with getting answers in Swift. Above methods are in Obj-C because I got it from old projects.

Comment: Did you find the solution to that crazy flickering of frame?

Answer (score 1):

You can save returned frames, and update their if new returned frames not close to your saved frames.
Also you can draw your frames little bigger and update their if returned frames lie beyond your frames.